# Deserialising to enum - ArgumentException: Requested value 'connected' was not found

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm using the following code generated by swagger to stand up a mock api. I'm getting an error while trying to deserialise a string to an enum.

Code:

```
string exampleJson = null;
exampleJson = "{\n  \"profileDescription\" : \"profileDescription\",\n  \"videoURL\" : \"http://example.com/aeiou\",\n  \"imageURL\" : \"http://example.com/aeiou\",\n  \"imageURLs\" : [ \"http://example.com/aeiou\", \"http://example.com/aeiou\" ],\n  \"name\" : \"name\",\n  \"connectedStatus\" : \"connected\",\n  \"id\" : \"046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91\",\n  \"businessType\" : \"businessType\",\n  \"infoGatherReason\" : \"infoGatherReason\"\n}";

var example = exampleJson != null
? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Enterprise>(exampleJson)
: default(Enterprise);
```

Enterprise.cs:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Enterprise : IEquatable<Enterprise>
{ 
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="imageURL")]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="profileDescription")]
    public string ProfileDescription { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="infoGatherReason")]
    public string InfoGatherReason { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="businessType")]
    public string BusinessType { get; set; }

    public enum ConnectedStatusEnum
    { 
        [EnumMember(Value = "connected")]
        ConnectedEnum = 1,

        [EnumMember(Value = "pending")]
        PendingEnum = 2,

        [EnumMember(Value = "notConnected")]
        NotConnectedEnum = 3
    }

    [DataMember(Name="connectedStatus")]
    public ConnectedStatusEnum? ConnectedStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="videoURL")]
    public string VideoURL { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="imageURLs")]
    public List<string> ImageURLs { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "connected" to type 'System.Nullable`1[CDPSpecDemo.Models.Enterprise+ConnectedStatusEnum]'. Path 'connectedStatus', line 7, position 33.'

Inner Exception

ArgumentException: Requested value 'connected' was not found.
```

Comment: Why not just name it "connected"? Adding "enum" at the end of the name isn't recommended.

Comment: The code was generated automatically by swagger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marking your enum class with JsonConverterAttribute should work

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum ConnectedStatusEnum
{ 
    [EnumMember(Value = "connected")]
    ConnectedEnum = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "pending")]
    PendingEnum = 2,

    [EnumMember(Value = "notConnected")]
    NotConnectedEnum = 3
}
```

Comment: Great ! See this answer for a customized "StringEnumConverter" https://stackoverflow.com/a/61685864/5466477