# Is possible to make json deserialize work with enum with assigned values?

Tags: c#, json.net

In our system, we have this enum and you can see the value starts with 1, not 0.

```
public enum EndType
    {
        [Description("DAYEND")]
        DayEnd = 1,
        [Description("MONTHEND")]
        MonthEnd = 2
    }
```

Then we have a request object that exposed through a web api and you can see that the PerformanceEndType doesn't have a default value.

```
public class AnnualisedPerformanceRequest
    {
        public EndType PerformanceEndType { get; set; };

        public bool UseDateRestrictMethod { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

Then when people post this JSON request to our web API:

```
{
    "UseDateRestrictMethod": true
}
```

The PerformanceEndType property actually has a value 0, which is not in the enum values we defined.

Of course, we can put a default value on this property for this request.

However, as we have a fair amount of enum properties in different request objects, is it possible to have some JSON setting or something, so when we call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request)`, it can work out that for this enum, the default value is 1 not 0?

Comment: Is a custom converter viable? That would be my first approach...

Comment: After bumping into this issue a few times in the past I got in the habit of any time an enum is deserilized in this manner to define an enum value for 0 of Unknown, then in code you can reject the request when an Unknown is the enum value. This helps define the difference between Not Initialized and Default enum value.

Comment: You can use a custom JsonConverter to solve this problem.  See [How can I ignore unknown enum values during json deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22752075/10263) for an example.  That question is really similar to yours.  You can customize the converter in the first answer to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EndType>(request);
```

**OR**

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnnualisedPerformanceRequest>(request);
```