# Deserializing multiple types and flattening object at the same time

Tags: c#, json.net

Given the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "ticker": "AAPL",
    "name": "Apple Inc.",
    "market": "STOCKS",
    "locale": "US",
    "currency": "USD",
    "active": true,
    "primaryExch": "NGS",
    "type": "cs",
    "codes": {
      "cik": "0000320193",
      "figiuid": "EQ0010169500001000",
      "scfigi": "BBG001S5N8V8",
      "cfigi": "BBG000B9XRY4",
      "figi": "BBG000B9Y5X2"
    },
    "updated": "2019-01-15T05:21:28.437Z",
    "url": "https://api.polygon.io/v2/reference/tickers/AAPL"
  },
  {
    "ticker": "$AEDAUD",
    "name": "United Arab Emirates dirham - Australian dollar",
    "market": "FX",
    "locale": "G",
    "currency": "AUD",
    "active": true,
    "primaryExch": "FX",
    "updated": "2019-01-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attrs": {
      "currencyName": "Australian dollar,",
      "currency": "AUD,",
      "baseName": "United Arab Emirates dirham,",
      "base": "AED"
    },
    "url": "https://api.polygon.io/v2/tickers/$AEDAUD"
  },
  { /* another stock */ },
  { /* another stock */ },
  { /* another FX*/ },
  { /* another stock */ },
  { /* another FX*/ }
  /* and so forth */
]
```

I wish to deserialize into a common list of type `List<Ticker>`:

```
class Ticker
{
   string Ticker {get; set;}
   string Name {get; set;}
   MarketEnum Market {get; set;}
   LocaleEnum Locale {get; set;}
   CurrencyEnum Currency {get; set;}
   bool Active {get; set;}
   PrimaryExchEnum PrimaryExch {get; set;}
   DateTimeOffset Updated {get; set;}
}

class Stock : Ticker
{
  int Type {get; set;}
  string CIK {get; set;}
  string FIGIUID {get; set;}
  string SCFIGI {get; set;}
  string CFIGI {get; set;}
  string FIGI {get; set;}
}

class ForeignExchange : Ticker
{
   BaseCurrencyEnum BaseCurrency {get; set;}
}
```

I have the following code:

```
class TickerConvertor : CustomCreationConverter<Ticker>
{
    public override Ticker Create(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Ticker Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        var type = (PrimaryExch)(int)jObject.Property("PrimaryExch");

        if (type == PrimaryExch.FX)
            return new ForeignExchange();
        else
            return new Stock();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader); // Load JObject from stream 
        var target = Create(objectType, jObject); // Create target object based on JObject 
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target); // Populate the object properties 

        return target;
    }
}
```

But I am unsure how I would deal with flattening of the `codes` sub-structure for the `Ticker` type, and `attrs` sub-structure for the `ForeignExchange` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle both the instantiation of the correct `Ticker` subclass and the flattening of the sub-structure from the JSON, you can implement a custom `JsonConverter` like this:

```
class TickerConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Ticker).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        Ticker ticker;
        JObject childObj;
        if (obj["market"].ToObject<MarketEnum>(serializer) == MarketEnum.FX)
        {
            ticker = new ForeignExchange();
            childObj = (JObject)obj["attrs"];
        }
        else
        {
            ticker = new Stock();
            childObj = (JObject)obj["codes"];
        }

        // populate common properties from the main object
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), ticker); 

        // also populate from the selected child object
        serializer.Populate(childObj.CreateReader(), ticker); 

        return ticker;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, you can either mark the `Ticker` class with `[JsonConverter(typeof(TickerConverter))]` or pass the converter to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.

But wait, some other changes are needed in your model classes before things will work:

1. All of your properties need to be `public`.
2. You can't have a property name be the same as the class that it is in.  In your case the offending property is `Ticker`.  You can either rename the class (e.g. `BaseTicker`) or rename the property (e.g. `Symbol`).  But if you rename the property you will need to mark it with `[JsonProperty("ticker")]` to preserve the mapping to the JSON.
3. In your `Stock` class the `Type` property is declared as `int` but in the JSON it is a string.  This will cause an error during deserialization.  The property needs to be declared as string.
4. You have defined various `enum` properties for many of the properties which are strings in the JSON.  You will get a conversion error during deserialization unless you use a `StringEnumConverter` with each enum.  You can do this by marking either the properties in your classes or the enums themselves with `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`.  I would opt for the latter.  But one other thing to consider: the `StringEnumConverter` that ships with Json.Net is very strict.  If a value appears in the JSON for which there is not a corresponding value defined in the enum, the converter will throw an error.  So you need to make sure that each enum has a complete set of all the possible values you might encounter for it.  If you want to make it more tolerant, you can instead use the `TolerantEnumConverter` shown in [How can I ignore unknown enum values during json deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22752075/10263)
5. The name of the `BaseCurrency` property in the `ForeignExchange` class does not match the JSON.  In the JSON it is called `base`.  So you will need to mark this property with `[JsonProperty("base")]`.

With the above changes made, the classes and enums should look something like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TickerConverter))]
class Ticker
{
    [JsonProperty("ticker")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MarketEnum Market { get; set; }
    public LocaleEnum Locale { get; set; }
    public CurrencyEnum Currency { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public PrimaryExchEnum PrimaryExch { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Updated { get; set; }
}

class Stock : Ticker
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string CIK { get; set; }
    public string FIGIUID { get; set; }
    public string SCFIGI { get; set; }
    public string CFIGI { get; set; }
    public string FIGI { get; set; }
}

class ForeignExchange : Ticker
{
    [JsonProperty("base")]
    public BaseCurrencyEnum BaseCurrency { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
enum MarketEnum { STOCKS, FX }

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
enum LocaleEnum { US, G }

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
enum CurrencyEnum { USD, AUD, EUR }

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
enum PrimaryExchEnum { NGS, FX }

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
enum BaseCurrencyEnum { AED }
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0WQLHT